# AWS API Gateway 10MB payload compression

Tags: aws-api-gateway, payload

I have a GET endpoint that sometimes returns a JSON payload larger than 10MB, thus giving me error code 500 as follows:

```
Execution failed due to configuration error: 
Integration response of reported length 10507522 is larger than allowed maximum of 10485760 bytes.
```

I was aware of the 10MB payload quota, so I enabled Content Encoding in the Settings and added the HTTP header `Accept-Encoding:gzip` to the request.

Now, payloads that were 7-8MB uncompressed are being sent with a size of about 350KB, so the compression works. Still, payloads over 10MB continue to give that same error.

Why does it keep giving me this error? Is it checking payload size before compression? How can I fix this?